# how to find the angle of Lovasz umbrella

Tags: geometry, graph-theory, euclidean-geometry, algebraic-graph-theory

in the book [Thirty-three Miniatures: Mathematical and Algorithmic Applications of](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiZiLz5iIzNAhWCbhQKHZ66CZUQFggfMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fkam.mff.cuni.cz%2F~matousek%2Fstml-53-matousek-1.pdf&usg=AFQjCNGxM9S-UDVWvACnHkZqZapnZNHZ1Q&sig2=myG41J5dD_MayYSBuqyMEg&bvm=bv.123664746,d.bGg) in problem 28 The Secret Agent and the Umbrella page 132 (pdf 140)

we want to find an orthogonal reperesentation of the graph C5 to do this the book says :

> To prove our main theorem we will need an interesting orthogonal
>   representation ρLU of the graph C5 in R3, the “Lov´asz umbrella”. Let
>   us imagine a collapsed umbrella with five ribs and the tube made of
>   the vector e1 = (1, 0, 0). Now we open it slowly until the moment
>   when all pairs of non-neighboring ribs become orthogonal:

[image]

> At this moment, the ribs define unit vectors v1, v2, . . . , v5. When
>   we assign the ith vertex of the graph C5 to the vector vi, we get an
>   orthogonal representation ρLU. It is easy to calculate the opening
>   angle of the umbrella: We obtain angle between vi , e1 is 5^(−1/4)

i want to prove that the angle between vi , e1 is 5^(−1/4). call it $\theta$

i mapped the umbrella to a plane so i got a pentagon since all the ribs have the same angle with the tube then it's a regular pentagon .

if i can find the radius of the circle then i can find the angle since the tube ,radius of the circle and one of the ribs make a right triangle since we know the ribs are of length 1 then $sin(\theta) = r$

to find r consider :

[image]

if i find y then $r = y/(2*sin(73))$

to find y i use the fact that we know non adjacent ribs must be orthogonal .
so consider the triangle made by two non adjacent ribs and y .
since this is also  a right triangle then $y = \sqrt2$

so $r = \sqrt2/(2*sin(73))$

so $\theta = sin^{-1}(\sqrt2/(2*sin(73)))$

which gives $\theta = 0.832202$

but 5^(−1/4) =  0.6687403

which are different . what am i doing wrong ?

Comment: $5^{-1/4}$ is the _cosine_ of the angle.

Comment: And then, $360°/5=72°$, not 73.

Answer (score 2):

We have $\sin (2\pi / 5) = \frac{\sqrt{10 + 2\sqrt{5}}}{4}$.
Hence,
$$
r = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{\sin (2\pi / 5)} = \frac{2}{\sqrt{5 + \sqrt{5}}}, 
$$
and
$$  
r^2 = \frac{4}{5 + \sqrt{5}} = 1 - \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}, \cos\theta = \sqrt{1 - r^2} = \frac{1}{\sqrt[4]{5}}.
$$

Comment: Can you explain how you got $r = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{\sin (2\pi / 5)}$. Are you applying the sine laws in the $r-r-y$ triangle? If so, isn't the big angle in the triangle $\frac{4Pi}{5}$?

Comment: Inasmuch as non-adjacent ribs are orthogonal, we have $y = \sqrt{2}$, using the notation  in the figure above. Then we get an isosceles triangle with sides $r,r,y = \sqrt{2}$ and top angle $\frac{4\pi}{5}$, and one can solve $r$ now.